# Youtube Cannot Loop (loop=1 in url)

Tags: html, youtube

I have a embedded Youtube video, and I have followed the parameter of loop=1 into the src, however it does not auto replay again, and showing the related video. (in wordpress)
Below is my html

```
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I73Nua1x3Ho?autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the playlist parameter with your video id as value like this:

```
<iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I73Nua1x3Ho?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=I73Nua1x3Ho" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The documentation on [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop), it explains that the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when he is associated with the playlist param.

**Edit:** FYI the AS3 player is described like this :

> The AS3 API allows users to control the YouTube video players by loading the player into a Flash application and making calls via ActionScript to the player's public API.

Comment: Thanks @Freelex. How do I get the playlist as the video is just a standalone video ?
Also, is it a must to include the playlist parameter otherwise it wont work ?

Comment: @LouisCheng Even if the video is a standalone, you can put the same id as your video id. In that case, it will only loop on one video, which is what you want. And yes, it looks like it's a must for compatibility reason.